# New line in different languages

Tags: java, newline, pascal, eol

I've encountered a problem while working on my testing system. I'm creating a file in Java, writing to it in Java, but reading from it in Pascal compilators. 
So, this may be not unclear, but when I do something like this in Java (Eclipse)

```
    File file = new File("D:/i.txt");
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));

    pw.print("hey\n");
    pw.print("you");
    bf.close();
    pw.close();
```

It gives me a file that looks like

> hey 
>   you

And when I run this code on Pascal language

```
begin
  assign(input,'D:/i.txt'); reset(input);
  while not eoln(input) do write(1);
 end.
```

Which means: Write "1" until you find a new line separator.
It won't stop to write ones.

But this is okay. Here is another strange thing: Pascal must have a line break or a line separator, or new line indicator and I found this to be  Char number 10 on ASCII table (LF, new line).

So, I decided to do other way.

```
    File file = new File("D:/i.txt");
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));

    pw.print("hey"+(char)10);
    pw.print("you");
    bf.close();
    pw.close();
```

This one would give me the same output file as the first bit of code ( at last apparently ).
But all my Pascal compilators still keep complaining and writing hundreds of ones.

How can I solve the problem with new lines?
Thank you.

Comment: it make sense each language has their own rules. have you seen the documentation of pascal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the infinite loop (writing hundreds of ones) is because you never read anything from the input so it is never at the end-of-line. Try putting a `read(input,ch);` in the loop.

Comment: Lol, that just made me feel so dumb now :\

Comment: @DenisRozimovschi so read(input,ch) is Java or Pascal?

Comment: I just forgot to place the read(). It works now even with "\n" and with "(char)10".

Comment: Pascal. `while not eoln(input) do begin read(input,ch); do write(1); end;`

Comment: Yeah. got it now. 
By the way, when you work with "input" and "output" you can use only read(ch), or write(ch).